# akka-http and JsonEntityStreamingSupport

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream, akka-http

I'm currently doing some experiment with akka and its persistency stack, wrapped with akka-http stack.

Note: For persistency, i'm using non-official plugin to persist Akka FSM to mongodb.

But my problem is using `JsonEntityStreamingSupport`, [recommended by akka to serve `Source` as json](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.9/scala/http/routing-dsl/source-streaming-support.html).

In my case, i have this piece of code

```
implicit val jsonEntityStreamingSupport: JsonEntityStreamingSupport = EntityStreamingSupport.json()

val readJournal = PersistenceQuery(system).readJournalFor[ScalaDslMongoReadJournal](MongoReadJournal.Identifier)

val route =
  path("workflows") {
    get {
      complete(readJournal.currentPersistenceIds())
    }
}

Http().bindAndHandle(route, "localhost", 8081)
```

But unfortunately, I came with this error:

```
$ curl localhost:8081/workflows
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

I do not see any errors or logs which could lead to information about why server is closing connection.

Does anyone already done this kind of experiment ?

I'm testing it with akka 2.4.16 and akka-http 10.0.5

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I figured it out.

`readJournal.currentPersistenceIds()` gives me a `Source[String, NotUsed]`.

But, as it is specified in [akka-http specs](https://github.com/akka/akka-http/blob/master/akka-http-tests/src/test/scala/akka/http/scaladsl/server/EntityStreamingSpec.scala),

> This is wrong since we try to render JSON, but String is not a valid
>   top level element we need to provide an explicit Marshaller[String,
>   ByteString] if we really want to render a list of strings.

So I have to provide a `Marshaller` for it. For example, as giving by those same tests :

```
implicit val stringFormat = Marshaller[String, ByteString] { ec ⇒ s ⇒
  Future.successful {
    List(Marshalling.WithFixedContentType(ContentTypes.`application/json`, () ⇒
      ByteString("\"" + s + "\"")) // "raw string" to be rendered as json element in our stream must be enclosed by ""
    )
  }
}
```